# Find the index of maximum value in numpy exclude zero values

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following numpy:

```
e = np.array([0, -1.3, 0, -3.9, 0, -0.9, 0])
```

I want to find the index of the maximum value in the list, but exclude 0.

The following code example returns first element in the list, because its value is 0.

```
result = np.argmax(e)
print(result)
```

But I want not to consider zeros in locating the maximum value:

The expected result should be `5` which is the index of the element with `-0.9` value.

I do not want to write code that will run on the list iteratively.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible approach would be:

```
import numpy as np

e = np.array([0, -1.3, 0, -3.9, 0, -0.9, 0])

result = np.nanargmax(np.where(e != 0, e, np.nan))
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
5
```

Note that this does not change the input array (in this case `e`).

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution would be to replace 0 with -np.inf

```
a[a == 0] = -np.inf
np.argmax(a)
>>> 5
```